# ng-show ng-hide in ng-repeat how to click/trigger for each wrapped block

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to click to hide/show divs just those divs/classes which are wrapped in `li` , now if I click the first item, both items become to show. Is there a way like jQuery to just check `this` in Angular ?

Online sample: http://jsfiddle.net/qp0x1zcc/

```
 <div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li ng-click="show = !show" ng-init='show = false'>
      <span ng-hide="show">{{item.name}}</span>
      <form ng-show="show">
        <input ng-model="item.name">
      </form>
    </li>
    <li ng-click="show = !show">
      <span ng-hide="show">{{item.d}}</span>
      <form ng-show="show">
        <input ng-model="item.d">
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Show is not related to any of these items.
You can use show[item.id] or store show state in item object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this. simple and clear.

```js
var editer = angular.module('editer', []);
function myCtrl($scope) {
$scope.index = -1;
  $scope.index2 = -1;
  $scope.items = [{
    name: "item #1",
    d: "names 1"
  }, {
    name: "item #2",
    d: "names 2"
  }, {
    name: "item #3",
    d: "names 3"
  }];
  $scope.setIndex = function(item){
    $scope.index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
     $scope.index2 = -1;
  
  }
    $scope.setIndex2 = function(item){
       $scope.index = -1;
     $scope.index2 = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
  
  }
  
  $scope.clearIndex = function(){
    $scope.index = -1;
     $scope.index2 = -1;
    }
  
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.container header {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul,
input,
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">


  <ul ng-repeat="item in items">

    <li ng-click="setIndex(item)"  ng-dblClick = "clearIndex()">
      <span ng-show="index != $index">{{item.name}}</span>
      <form ng-show="index == $index">
        <input ng-model="item.name">
      </form>
    </li>
     <li ng-click="setIndex2(item)"  ng-dblClick = "clearIndex()">
           <span ng-show="index2 != $index">{{item.d}}</span>
      <form ng-show="index2 == $index">
        <input ng-model="item.d">
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but could they be clicked individually  ? not together

Comment: means item.id and item.name be individually ?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, but when I click item #3, item #3 and names 3 are both activated

Comment: i updated answer. i suggest this answer because i don't want add extra data into array. if not problem for you  that add extra info to array, its good way as @ Mateusz Sip said.

Comment: Awesome answer! but don't understand why ` ng-dblClick = "clearIndex()"` ? why need it to be double click? thanks

Comment: ng-dblClick = "clearIndex()" for when u don't need to any of li tag be in edit mode.