# AngularJS edit and save values inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, frontend

I'm working on my first angular app and i dont know the best way to handle this problem.

I have a long hierarchical json becouse the tables of the database are like a pyramid, looks similar to this: 
[image]

I have the view represented pretty well using ng-repeat, I want to be able to edit the last rows of the last table which correspond with last level of JSON.

To do this I have implemented a edit modal that works fine, it saves and updates the database perfectly, the problem is that to see the updated value i have to refresh the page losing scroll position and collapsing accordions which is very bad.

Images of accordions:

[image]

When i click edit icon a promise stores in $scope.objEdit = {}; the object and launches the modal, which is linked to this object by ng-model.

So I think that the next step is that when modal is closed, i have to override the old object placed in the $scope variable that contains the entire json for the edited one, but im not sure how to do it.

I would appreciate your help to learn the standard way to do this, thx mates.

I Just solved it, I used a similar procedure to the oen that @AnikIslamAbhi sugested, in the fiddle that @Harshad shared in the comments is solved, but i have a much more dificult json to handle, i had to go with things like those to get the index of all levels of the json:

```
$scope.positionEvaluacion = $scope.dataEvaluacion.indexOf(args.levelOne);
$scope.positionAsignaturaevaluacion = $scope.dataEvaluacion[$scope.positionEvaluacion].asignaturaevaluacion.indexOf(args.levelTwo);
$scope.positionTarea = $scope.dataEvaluacion[$scope.positionEvaluacion].asignaturaevaluacion[$scope.positionAsignaturaevaluacion].tarea.indexOf(args.levelThree);
```

And after this override this object with the edited one:

```
$scope.dataEvaluacion[$scope.positionEvaluacion].asignaturaevaluacion[$scope.positionAsignaturaevaluacion].tarea[$scope.positionTarea] = $scope.objEdit;
```

Comment: Can you show use more code? How do you set the new data?

Comment: Have you tried anything? So that we can help easily

Comment: visit this http://jsfiddle.net/Thw8n/4/

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637817/ng-show-ng-hide-in-ng-repeat-how-to-click-trigger-for-each-wrapped-block/36639051#36639051

Comment: When i click the plus icon it goes to a diferent /new url and after insert the new data returns to the main page, it has the same problem, lose scroll position and collapse accordions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this procedure

1. Pass the selected object on edit click from UI to Controller.
2. Clone it and pass that object to modal.
3. OnModal close pass the modal object back to the UI.
4. Copy the values of modal object to the previous selected object

Like this

```
for(var i in modalObj){
  selectedObj[i]=modalObj[i];
}
```

Comment: When i click edit icon a promises stores in $scope.objEdit = {}; the object and launches the modal, which is linked to this object by ng-model.

So I think that the next step is that when modal is closed i have to override the old object for this one in the $scope variable that contains the entire json, but im not sure how to do it.

Comment: @RubénMartín can you provide a demo in jsfiddle ?

Comment: i just solved it, thx to you @ AnikIslamAbhi and this link http://jsfiddle.net/Thw8n/4/ that shared @Harshad
thx for your answer